# Change background color with Angular animations

Tags: angular, css-transitions, linear-gradients, angular-animations

I want to change my gradient background color to another one when clicked a button. Here's an example from [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations) as i show below. This code works fine with normal colors(changes slowly during 1000ms -as what i want-) but not for gradient colors (changes immediately after 1000ms).

```
animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('black', style({
         background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #2c2d34, #242424)'
      })),
      state('green',   style({
         background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #2c2d34, #467a5e)'
      })),
  transition('black => green', animate('1000ms ease-out')),
  transition('green => black', animate('1000ms ease-in'))
])


<section class="bg-area" [@heroState]="state"></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear-Gradient seem not to support tansitions as of now, so you would have to find a work-around for that. Something you could try could be setting the opacity of two elements which overlay each other. Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qidyqd).

It's definitly not an ideal solution but to kick off an idea for now and maybe it helps you

Comment: Thanks it worked after a little changes. The opacity makes disappear every element in <section> so i used it in an absolute <div> behind the <section> and made section background transparent. Saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

> This code works fine with normal colors(changes slowly during 1000ms -as what i want-) but not for gradient colors (changes immediately after 1000ms)

The reason for this is that `linear-gradient` is [not an animatable css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

As the other answer mentioned, you can use a hacky approach using opacity and pseudo elements. Here is a nice tutorial on doing exactly this: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759

Answer (score 0):

If your looking looking to transition gradients you could play with pseudo elements or changing opacity. Apply same idea to animations: [] if you wish.

```js
<div class="greenbg" [ngClass]="{'show' : isSolved, 'hide': !isSolved}"></div>
<div class="graybg" [ngClass]="{'show' : !isSolved, 'hide': isSolved}"></div>
```

```css
.greenbg {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(161, 255, 67,0.4) 0%, #1a1a1a 100%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.graybg {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.4) 0%, #1a1a1a 100%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```
isSolved = false;
```